# Why some planets revolve around Sun in opposite direction than that of Earth?

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, planets, solar-system

Why some planets in universe revolve around sun in opposite direction of the direction in which earth revolve around sun?  Please help me to find the answer of this question.

Comment: Let me ask the inverse of this question: do you know of anything that would *force* every single planet to revolve a certain way around its star? Along the same lines, do planets' orbits necessarily have to be fixed after their formations?

Comment: Anyway, consider Uranus. Its rotation axis is tilted 90 degrees from the plane of the solar system, so it is widely believed to have been hit by something quite large to cause this.

Comment: and your answer uranus is not valid for all planets

Comment: It doesn't have to be, as that wasn't my point. Many planets go their entire lives without being hit by something (or pulled by something) significant enough to change their orbital trajectories. But some do. Uranus is an example of such an event.

Comment: oh hope so but this does not clarify my answer

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, then. If you're wondering how (as in the case of Venus) retrograde motion arises in solar system formation, I must warn you that theories of planetary formation are still under construction, and that era is not very well understood. Therefore, you are not likely to get a satisfactory answer for a decade or two.

Comment: Why should all planets in the universe revolve the same way as Earth around our Sun? Why should there be any link at all to our Earth? What does "same direction" even mean - are you only talking about planets in our own solar system?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

According to the theory of Jefimenko and of de Mees, the operation of co-gravitation over a period of time will cause planets to rotate in the same direction as the orbit, and will cause a planet near to the centre to go into some sort of phase-lock where the orbit and the day are in a simple ratio, usually 1:1 as is the earth/moon.

It is worth noting, though that while the natural order is for prograde rotations and revolutions, the retrograde orbits etc are an indication of recent events, which have not settled down.  For example, the capture of a passing cloud or body might settle down into a retrograde orbit.

It is likely that the exoplanets orbit close enough to the stars to be influenced by the magnetic fields of the stars.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers OPs question. OP wants to know why done planets revolve differently than earth, your answer talks about how planets rotate the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50684/discussion-on-answer-by-wendy-krieger-why-some-planets-revolve-around-sun-in-opp).

Comment: your answer is not according to my question and the answer did not  clarify the question very well